# R - Converting integer into date

Tags: r, date

I have integers like the following:

41764 41764 42634 42634 42445 42445 41792 41807 41813 41842 41838 41848 41849 41837

Which need to be converted into date, the time doesn't matter.

I'm told that when it's converted it should be in the year 2014, current conversions I've tried have either given the year as 1984 or 2084.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like that ? `as.Date(42634, origin = "1898-01-01")`

Comment: @MFR An origin of 1900-01-01 would probably be closer

Comment: This is puzzling.  If we assume these are in days indexed from some date, the min and max are 870 days apart. So they can't be in units of days if they're all in 2014. So if the units are smaller than days, then what are they? `as.Date((s-min(s))/(max(s)-min(s))*364,origin="2014-01-01")` works but I doubt that's what you want???

Comment: I guess based on the answers that you don't need them to *all* be in 2014 ...

Answer (score 3):

Sam Firke's `janitor` package includes a function for cleaning up this Excel mess:

```
x <- c(41764L, 41764L, 42634L, 42634L, 42445L, 42445L, 41792L, 41807L, 
       41813L, 41842L, 41838L, 41848L, 41849L, 41837L)

janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(x)
##  [1] "2014-05-05" "2014-05-05" "2016-09-21" "2016-09-21" "2016-03-16" "2016-03-16" "2014-06-02"
##  [8] "2014-06-17" "2014-06-23" "2014-07-22" "2014-07-18" "2014-07-28" "2014-07-29" "2014-07-17"
```

Excel reader functions likely take care of this for you, which would be the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your have Excel date integers here. Microsoft Office Excel stores dates as sequential numbers that are called serial values. For example, in Microsoft Office Excel for Windows, January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,448 days after January 1, 1900.

Please note Excel incorrectly assumes that the year 1900 is a leap year. No problem when calculating today only.

[image]

Microsoft Excel correctly handles all other leap years, including century years that are not leap years (for example, 2100). Only the year 1900 is incorrectly handled.

See [Microsoft Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214326) for further information.

There is a offset of two days between the R script proposed by @loki and a calculation in Excel.

[image]

Please read following date conversion help documents (snippet see below):

```
## date given as number of days since 1900-01-01 (a date in 1989)
as.Date(32768, origin = "1900-01-01")
## Excel is said to use 1900-01-01 as day 1 (Windows default) or
## 1904-01-01 as day 0 (Mac default), but this is complicated by Excel
## incorrectly treating 1900 as a leap year.
## So for dates (post-1901) from Windows Excel
as.Date(35981, origin = "1899-12-30") # 1998-07-05
## and Mac Excel
as.Date(34519, origin = "1904-01-01") # 1998-07-05
## (these values come from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214330)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `as.Date()` as @MFR pointed out. However, use the `origin` 1900-01-01

```
x <- c(41764, 41764, 42634, 42634, 42445, 42445, 41792, 41807, 
       41813, 41842, 41838, 41848, 41849, 41837)

as.POSIXct.as.Date(x, origin = "1900-01-01")
# [1] "2014-05-07" "2014-05-07" "2016-09-23" "2016-09-23" "2016-03-18"
# [6] "2016-03-18" "2014-06-04" "2014-06-19" "2014-06-25" "2014-07-24"
# [11] "2014-07-20" "2014-07-30" "2014-07-31" "2014-07-19"
```

Comment: They are supposed to be in 2014

Comment: You can just use `as.Date(x, origin = "1900-01-01")`, but both seem to be off by two days for reasons I don't understand; I really doubt the origin used was `"1899-12-30"`.